# Web frontend button click html tag not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

```
class Application extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return [div]
      [button onclick={() => {console.log('click'}}]button[/button]
    [/div];
  }
}

React.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

I have the above code in my react app, render component. Nothing happens as nothing print in console.

Comment: Can you provide all of the code for the entire component?

Comment: `<button onClick={() => {console.log('clicked')}}> button </button>`

Comment: Are you using any `prettier`? `<` and `>` getting converted to `[` and `]`.

Comment: onclick is wrong .  onClick is true

Answer (score 5):

React uses `camelCase`. `onclick` should be `onClick`.

```
<button onClick={() =>{console.log('clicked')}}>button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just that you have made a syntax mistake here. React uses camelCase for event handlers.

For example, the HTML:

```
<button onclick="activateLasers()">
  Activate Lasers
</button>
```

is slightly different in React:

```
<button onClick={activateLasers}>
  Activate Lasers
</button>
```

So your code becomes:

```
class Application extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return ( 
      <div>
       <button onClick={() => {console.log('click'}}]button </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

React.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```